# ServiceStack ORMLite LeftJoin confusion

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a simple Vendor -> Product relation with the following setup (non-relevant properties elided):

```
public class Vendor
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<Product> Products {get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get ; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Vendor))]
    public Guid VendorId {get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a soft delete in this case and tried using a `LeftJoin()` to retrieve the Vendor with a list of referenced and non-deleted Products. My first attempts were unsuccessful and I think the issue with the left join was that I was trying to use `LoadSelect()` to populate the entity with references using the `LeftJoin()` query. But actually the join was being used to identify the Vendor and `LoadSelect()` then populated the Products for that Vendor. After much testing and googling I have the following code which works but is a two step process.

```
public async Task<Vendor> GetVendorProductsAsync(Guid vendorId)
{
    using (var con = DbFactory.Open())
    {
        try
        {
            var vendor = (await con.SelectAsync<Vendor>(v => v.Id == vendorId && !v.IsDeleted)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (vendor != null)
            {
                var products = await con.SelectAsync<Product>(p => p.VendorId == vendorId && !p.IsDeleted);
                vendor.Merge(products);
            }
            return vendor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "{@LastSql}", con.GetLastSql());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer to use the database to perform the join and then ORMLite to load the entity with the Vendor and referenced/filtered Products in a single step. Using ORMLite is it possible to use a `LeftJoin()` to load only the referenced Products where `IsDeleted` is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered queries on `LoadSelect` only impacts the the Vendors queried, it's not used to filter the Vendors referenced product data and there's currently no way to change which referenced data it loads.

So the available solutions is to make separate requests and use the [POCO merge API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#merge-disconnected-poco-result-sets) as you're doing or to use `LoadSelect` but remove the deleted products on the client after, e.g:

```
var vendors = db.LoadSelect<Vendor>(x => !x.IsDeleted); 
vendors.Products.RemoveAll(x => x.IsDeleted);
```

Comment: That's good info thank you - given the small number of products per vendor, removing on the client is probably the most performant and saves a network request.